# ReadOnly properties with ExpandableObjectConverter TypeConverter do not display as ReadOnly in PropertyGird

Tags: windows, vb.net, readonly, propertygrid

Windows PropertyGrid displays readonly properties as ReadOnly in the propertygrid. Specifically, the property value is colored gray instead of black and it cannot be edited in the propertygrid.  This is standard behavior of the Windows PropertyGrid control.

The problem I am having is that when I add an ExpandableObjectConverter typeconverter to the readonly property, it no longer follows this behavior. When the converter is expanded to show the subproperties of the property, all of the subproperties appear in black and can be edited.  This is incorrect behavior, because if the property is readonly, then by definition all of its subproperties should also be readonly.

Is this a bug in the propertygrid control?  If the PropertyGrid control does not handle this situation as I expect it to, is there anything I can do to force it to have the behavior I want, which is:

1. If the parent property is readonly, then all child properties are readonly.
2. When expanded, all child properties of the readonly property should be displayed in gray and the user should be unable to edit them.

Comment: Can you show the property?  I think all you have to do is add the `ReadOnly` attribute

Comment: This is expected behavior, what's marked as readonly is the property itself, ie: the object *reference* when the property's type is an object. Changing that behavior like you want is complicated, you could create a wrapper for the object you want to be "readonly", with readonly properties, or with ReadOnly attribute to all wrapped properties.